# Remove usage of generic wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube, polymorphism, jsonschema

In my project I use classes representing Json Schemas, in particular:

```java
public interface JsonSchema {
    String getId();
    JsonTypedSchema<? extends FieldValue> getTypedSchema(Map<String, JsonSchema> schemas);
}


@Value
public class ReferenceToAJsonSchema implements JsonSchema {
    @JsonProperty("$id")
    String id;
    @JsonProperty("$ref")
    String reference;

    @Override
    public JsonTypedSchema<? extends FieldValue> getTypedSchema(Map<String, JsonSchema> schemas) {
        return schemas.get(reference).getTypedSchema(schemas);
    }
}

public interface JsonTypedSchema<T extends FieldValue> extends JsonSchema {
    String getType();

    @Override
    default JsonTypedSchema<? extends FieldValue> getTypedSchema(Map<String, JsonSchema> schemas) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

`getTypedSchema` should give me the "effective" type of the schema by following references recursively (`schemas` is a map of all schemas indexed by their `$id`).

Sonar gives me a [Remove usage of generic wildcard type](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452) Critical issue, but I fail to see how to fix it...

Do you see any alternative?

---

P.S. : There are questions close to mine, but mine is more specific, so I was simply wondering if in my case, there were any alternative

Comment: I ignore these warnings. Sonar wants you to use concrete types, but there is a big difference between for instance `List<T>` and `List<? extends T>`. The compiler allows you to add elements to the former but not the latter.

Comment: The only way would be to add a type variable to the `JsonSchema` interface, say, `F extends FieldValue`, and use it in the return type of `getTypedSchema`. Or, add another method to `JsonTypedSchema`, which allows you to access the non-wildcard value if you know you have an instance of `JsonTypedSchema` (although, then there's not much point, as you could just use the reference directly).

Comment: I tried your first idea @AndyTurner, but sadly, even if `getTypedSchema`'s return type is JsonTypedSchema<T>, `schemas`' values type is still `JsonSchema<?>`, so `return schemas.get(reference).getTypedSchema(schemas);` won't work :/

Comment: According to the link you provided, the fix is changing return type to `JsonTypedSchema<FieldValue>`. Is that not working?

Comment: @CidTori well, yes. The compiler can't know what the types of the child schemas are.

Comment: @Chaosfire Nope, I tried : then I can't `return this;` in `JsonTypedSchema` :/